# Xcode Watchkit no executables in Edit Scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit

I am trying to create different schemes in Xcode for the Watchkit app - one for Notification and one for Glance.

When I duplicate the Watchkit scheme, and then go to "Edit scheme", to change the Executable in the Run tab, there is only the main executable there, and not the one I just duplicated.

I tryed everything.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest beta of Xcode 6.2 WatchKit automatically creates the Schemes for Glance and Notification.

Answer (score 1):

In the Edit Scheme Window, click on the Run icon in the left panel. Next, look to the right panel and where it says "Watch Interface", click on the word "Main" and change to the appropriate option.

Comment: If you need to rename your Xcode project all of the automatically created schemes are basically reset and you need to redo them. This was the answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You have select watchkitInterface and you will see static, dynamic notification and glance in that.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode Schemes manage *build targets*. Apple Watch Notifications and Glances are not created as separate targets.

They are designed with Glance Interface Controller and Notification Interface Controller objects on your Storyboard within your WatchKit app, and supported with code in your WatchKit App Extension (and potentially elsewhere, for the source of notifications).

[image: Glance and Notification Interface Controller objects in Xcode interface builder]

Therefore, they cannot be managed with a build scheme. May be useful to review what you were you trying to achieve functionally with this action. There may be another way to achieve it. If, for instance, you want to have just a Glance or Notification interface without having a WatchKit App, you simply create a Storyboard in your WatchKit App that only includes Glance and/or Notification Interface controllers, and not a standard WKInterfaceController. The Apple Watch will do the rest.